# Is it possible to query Wikipedia's API for all users specifying language group?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am looking for a way to query Wikipedia's API to retrieve a list of users that have specified they are part of the group en-N (i.e. native speaker's of English). I am able to get similar examples working where I query the API for other groups, but am unable to figure out how to specifically get the language groups. I am able to query for the group 'bureaucrat'.

Query:

```
user_query = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allusers&augroup=bureaucrat&aulimit=5&format=xml').read()
```

Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><api><query-continue><allusers aufrom="Avraham" /></query-continue><query><allusers><u userid="3030741" name="28bytes" /><u userid="2530149" name="Acalamari" /><u userid="642191" name="Addshore" /><u userid="13732" name="Andrevan" /><u userid="3271817" name="Anonymous Dissident" /></allusers></query></api>
```

I am trying to figure what the correct group name is for en-N. When I try

```
user_query = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?  action=query&list=allusers&augroup=en-N&aulimit=5&format=xml').read()
```

My output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><api><query-continue><allusers aufrom="! ! ! ! !" /></query-continue><warnings><allusers xml:space="preserve">Unrecognized value for parameter 'augroup': en-N</allusers></warnings><query><allusers><u userid="399769" name=" - )" /><u userid="146308" name="!" /><u userid="480659" name="! !" /><u userid="505506" name="! ! !" /><u userid="553517" name="! ! ! !" /></allusers></query></api>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no such group. [Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aListGroupRights) in MediaWiki are all about user rights management.

If you are looking for all users who have included an `en-N` [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBabel) in their userpage, you can get those userpages from the [Category:User en-N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aUser_en-N). To list them via the api, have a look at the [Categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers).